# Local name resolution with nfs

Tags: networking, server, nfs

I have a computer with ubuntu 14.04.3 freshly installed, where I can mount its nfs export using its ip address, but not by using its name. Specifically, I get the following result on the client:

```
<client>:~# showmount -e dell.local
clnt_create: RPC: Port mapper failure - Unable to receive: errno 111 (Connection refused)
<client>:~# showmount -e 10.0.2.4
Export list for 10.0.2.4:
/ 10.0.0.0/8
```

I have another system that I set up exactly the same (I mean, I used the same set of scripts to set it up, it really should be exactly the same, except for the name ofcourse). Everything works on that system from the same client.

The problem server responded with the same error initially even using its ip address. Restarting nfs-kernel-server made the ip address approach work.

I wish I could give more information, but I have been at this for hours and I honestly don't even know what would be relevent. I've tried restarting nfs-kernel-server multiple times. I have tried using multiple clients. I've even reinstalled the OS. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

EDIT:

A commentor suggested I try pinging the server from itself. I did, and the  output was similar to what I get when I ping from a client (I can copy over the exact output, but I'd have to do it by hand and I can't see it being helpful, this is the exact output pinging from a client):

```
<client>:~# ping dell.local
PING dell.local (10.0.2.6) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 10.0.2.6: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.184 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.6: icmp_seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.243 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.6: icmp_seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.207 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.6: icmp_seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.193 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.6: icmp_seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.290 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.6: icmp_seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.233 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.6: icmp_seq=7 ttl=64 time=0.255 ms
64 bytes from 10.0.2.6: icmp_seq=8 ttl=64 time=0.227 ms
^C
```

EDIT 2:

```
<user>@dell:/data# rpcinfo -p
   program vers proto   port  service
    100000    4   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   tcp    111  portmapper
    100000    4   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    3   udp    111  portmapper
    100000    2   udp    111  portmapper
    100024    1   udp  58196  status
    100024    1   tcp  57892  status
    100003    2   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   tcp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   tcp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   tcp   2049
    100227    3   tcp   2049
    100003    2   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    3   udp   2049  nfs
    100003    4   udp   2049  nfs
    100227    2   udp   2049
    100227    3   udp   2049
    100021    1   udp  47379  nlockmgr
    100021    3   udp  47379  nlockmgr
    100021    4   udp  47379  nlockmgr
    100021    1   tcp  41662  nlockmgr
    100021    3   tcp  41662  nlockmgr
    100021    4   tcp  41662  nlockmgr
    100005    1   udp  41182  mountd
    100005    1   tcp  43363  mountd
    100005    2   udp  59166  mountd
    100005    2   tcp  59611  mountd
    100005    3   udp  42491  mountd
    100005    3   tcp  54650  mountd
```

EDIT 3:

Here is the contents of /etc/hosts on the client (replacing the client host name with 'client'):

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   client

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And on the server:

```
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   dell

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters
```

And here is /etc/exports on the server:

```
/ 10.0.0.0/8(rw,fsid=0,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,sync,insecure)
```

Note that, regarding the obvious security concerns with the above, this is a special purpose network that only I have physical access to, and to which only I know the wireless password.

Comment: is your client system resolving your local domain  `dell.local` . try `ping dell.local`

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I incorporated my results into an edit. I will note that the pings took just over a milisecond each on the server, while they only took on the order of .2 from the client. The client is a much higher quality machine.

Answer (score 0):

you can edit your /etc/hosts files and add a line like the example below:

192.168.1.2  server.servername.com server

This makes "server.servername.com", and "server" resolve to the IP 192.168.1.2

Alternatively you can install a DHCP server, I can send you to a good how to if thats your goal as well.

**ALSO:  Be sure your ports are open, and all of the RPC services are running (portmapper, etc) 
TRY:
rpcinfo -p**

[mattcurry.com](http://mattcurry.com)

Comment: cat your /etc/hosts, and ufw status numbered

Comment: I included the output of the suggested command, I can't see problems in it, but I am new to networking. Being new to it, I may be incorrect, but it is my understanding that the firewall in ubuntu is disabled by default, and so there should be no closed ports on a fresh install. Is that correct?

Comment: ufw status numbered gives the output "inactive". I have not added any entries to /etc/hosts, as it would be a significant advantage for my setup to be able to introduce new systems without explicitly dealing with existing systems, it is my goal to achieve such a setup. It seems possible given the fact that the name for the other server resolves without any prep on the client end.

Comment: what is the mount command you are issuing?  Where is that server located?  Can you show me the contents of /etc/exports on the nfs server?

Comment: I am issuing "showmounts -e" and /etc/hosts has the default contents for Ubuntu 14.04.3, I will post that when I get back to the server in a half hour (I had to run offsite). The server is connected to a wireless router that is connected by wire to the client. The server that worked is connected the same way as the other server.

Comment: In the last comment I meant "showmount -e", I accidentily included an 's'. The output is posted in the question. And I just added the exact contents of /etc/hosts.

Comment: Sorry, I misread what you asked for, I will go include /etc/exports in the question.